# Windows 10 forces itself to boot

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, multi-boot

I have a duel boot set up on one of my computers using two drives, windows 10 and windows 7. Recently, I haven't been able to boot to windows 7. I eventually found I could unplug the windows 10 drive until windows 7 boots, but I think constantly plugging a hard drive into my computer while it's on isn't a good idea, even though the bios supports hot plugging drives. On another windows 10 computer I have, I am unable to boot to a flash drive on that computer, but I can on another computer without windows 10, I have biited from flash drives previously  with that computer, with the same flash drive, but I can't unplug the hard drive in that computer.

I have turned off safe boot, changed boot order, manually selected the drive and even used a boot loader made for windows. Nothing has worked on either computer.

Comment: Have you checked that computer's secure boot setting? Windows 10 registers itself with secure boot durring installation which, if it hadn't been done before, fully enables it. If you then try to boot from external media it would either ignore the external media outright or display an error.

Comment: And no, hot plugging a drive that isn't designed for doing so is not a good idea. It's something to try in desperate situations but should never be SOP.

Comment: secure boot is disabled on both computers

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you installed W10 with the W7 hard drive connected.

Therefore, W10 has written its files on the W7 boot area.

If you don't want this to happen, install W10 without the W7 HDD connected.